# CSS Dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

Is there any good css dropdown menu solution to use in regular html website?
Or using javascript is better?

Comment: Yes, yes there are. And no, JS is not 'better,' but might be more useful, depending on your needs. Speaking of 'your needs,' what are they? What do you want us to help you achieve with this question? Incidentally, I'll point you to [Stu Nicholl's CSS Play website](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/) for a demo of what's out there with **just** html/css.

Comment: I just need really simple one. no effects, nothing. Just be readable and cross-browser. I mean, vertical dropdown

Comment: @user194076: and where have you **started**? What have you **tried**? What **happened**, what went **wrong**..? I'm not trying to be combative, and I'll happily offer help, but you're offering us no insight as to what you want **help** with. Your question seems to be "give me a drop-down menu," which *isn't* a *question*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/) is my current favourite CSS dropdown menu solution. The site also presents a lot of great themes. I would recommend reading through the HTML and CSS to understand how everything works so you can build on this solution.

Comment: This answer does not meet current SO standards. Please update to include more content in the answer itself. This post doesn't even contain the name of the library.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one, css-only, solution. Because I've got no idea as to what you want to present in your menu I can only offer you a basic solution that you'll have to adapt to your needs, however here's the html and css:

#### html:

```
<ul>
    <li>First list item</li>
    <li>Second list item</li>
    <li>Third, with a dropdown
        <ul>
            <li>First sub-item</li>
            <li>Second sub-item</li>
            <li>Third, with a fly-out
                <ul>
                    <li>Flyout one</li>
                    <li>Flyout two</li>
                    <li>Flyout three</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Fourth sub-item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Fourth list item</li>
</ul>
```

#### css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: #ffa;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
}

ul li ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10em;
}

ul li ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}

ul li ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ul li ul li:hover ul li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FT8q8/).

Comment: Works beautifully, I am shocked this isn't the selected answer

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this, but Fiddle demo is not working.

Answer (score 0):

[DynamicDrive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/) has a lot of free css menus.